# Accessing this.userId not working when calling from within Meteor.SetTimeout

Tags: meteor

I've been trying to access the `this.userId` variable from within a Meteor.methods call, but it doesn't seem to work when I try to call the method via Meteor.setTimeout or Meteor.setInterval.

This is what I've got:

```
if (Meteor.is_server) {
    Meteor.methods({
        getAccessToken : function() {
            try {
                console.log(this.userId);
                return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).services.facebook.accessToken;
            } catch(e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });

    var fetch_feed = function() {
        console.log(Meteor.call("getAccessToken"));
        [...] // A bunch of other code
    };

    Meteor.startup(function() {
        Meteor.setInterval(fetch_feed, 60000); // fetch a facebook group feed every minute
        Meteor.setTimeout(fetch_feed, 3000); // initially fetch the feed after 3 seconds
    });
}
```

Watching the terminal log, the `this.userId` always returns a null. But if I try calling the method from the client side, or through the console, it returns the correct ID.

How come this doesn't work from within a Meteor.setInterval? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does `this.userId` point to `null` or are is `getAccessToken` returning `null` because you catch the exception and force it to?

Comment: The error from `getAccessToken` is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'services' of undefined`, because `this.userId` is returning `null`. If I call the method from console it works, but from `Meteor.setTimeout` or `Meteor.setInterval` it fails.

Comment: BTW. If I move the setTimeout and setInterval over to the client side, this works fine. It's like this.userId isn't available when called from the server side. But based on the documentation, it should be available anywhere: http://docs.meteor.com/#method_userId

Comment: `this.userId` is probably null because there is no user session and hence no user in `Meteor.startup`, since the startup method is called when the server starts, before a user has been able to access the server from a client and log in.

Comment: Well, I did try having the Meteor.setTimeout not within Meteor.startup, but that didn't work either. Also, I am logged in and this.userId does return the correct value when the method is called from the client side. But based on the documentation, this.userId should be accessible both on the client and server side, and it should be a reactive variable, so I don't get why the server can't access it, even though the method is being called from a timeout. How am I supposed to periodically access the userId on the server side, if not with a setInterval?

Comment: Why not throw it in a `Meteor.autorun` instead of a `Meteor.timeout`, this way you know when the user will be logged in? you can make it only run once using a boolean check

Comment: @Akshat Can you write that up as an answer with an example so that I can test it out?

Comment: Oh and by the way, I don't want it to only run once. I want it to run periodically, as in once every minute.

Comment: Could you give a bit of how you're calling `getAccessToken` from the client?

Comment: @Akshat When I call it from a client, it doesn't matter where I call it from. I can call `Meteor.call('getAccessToken', function(err, data) { console.log(err, data); });` from dev tools console and it returns the access token. I can call it from Meteor.setInterval, on the client side, and it returns the access token. The only thing not working here is setting up a periodic call, via Meteor.setInterval, **on the server side** and calling the method from there. Doing this results in a nullified this.userId ... which shouldn't happen, based on the documentation.

Comment: @MaggiTrymbill, it would be great if you could share how you solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor userId's are associated with client connections.  The server may interact with many clients and `this.userId` inside a method will tell you which client has asked for the method to be run.

If the server uses Meteor.call() to run a method then it will not have a userId since it is not running for any client.

The methods allow clients to call for functions to be run on the server.  For things the server will trigger itself a javascript function will do.

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution I used - sometimes you do not want to make the method a function but really want it to remain a method. In that case, a hack to make this work:

```
            var uniqueVar_D8kMWHtMMZJRCraiJ = Meteor.userId();
            Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
                    // hack to make Meteor.userId() work on next async 
                    // call to current method
                    if(! Meteor._userId) Meteor._userId = Meteor.userId;
                    Meteor.userId = function() {
                        return Meteor._userId() || uniqueVar_D8kMWHtMMZJRCraiJ
                    };
                    Meteor.apply(methodName, args);
                }
            , 100);
```

Some brief explanation: we save `Meteor.userId` in `Meteor._userId` and overwrite `Meteor.userId` with a function that returns `Meteor._userId()` if it is true and otherwise the historic value of `Meteor.userId()` before any of this happened. That historic value is saved in an impossible to occur twice var name so that no context conflicts can happen.

Comment: does this support multiple users?  What happens when a 2nd meteor call comes in before the timeout is resolved?  Also, what's the point of having the random chars in the var name if it's the same every time.  Are you just uncluttering the scope?

Comment: wow, no, don't do this. It's a bad hack that will cause many issues. user728291's answer is the correct one